# Unable to get file to load in child theme

Tags: magento2.4

I took the file located at

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/type/default.phtml
```

and moved it to

```
app/design/frontend/Mycompany/luma_child/Magento_Catalog/template/product/view/type/default.phtml
```

I then redeployed and cleared the cache but no matter what I do I can not get this file in my child theme to load. Other files work/load just fine in my child theme.

I am not sure even where to begin to trouble shoot this?

Comment: In path hints which file path it shows?

Comment: can you please mention the code of your default.phtml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template folder is "templates" instead of "template"

You can try with

`app/design/frontend/Mycompany/luma_child/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/type/default.phtml`